# Angular Error [$injector:modulerr] when loading module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

[Update] I've found the site works with Microsoft Edge just fine.  IE seems to be the only one having issues.

So I've run into an issue where my site fails to load in Internet Explorer and throws this error:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module necs due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module necs.LandingModule.controller due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'necs.LandingModule.controller' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

The site loads completely fine in both Firefox and Chrome, but refuses to load in Internet Explorer.  I'm not sure what the issue could be as the 'necs.LandingModule.controller' is both spelled correctly and loaded.  I've tried removing some of the code within the Controller to see if it would load, hoping that I could find exactly which piece of code IE doesn't like, but I've yet to be successful in doing that.

Let me know if you need more information and I will provide as needed.

**CONTROLLER.JS**

```
angular.module('necs.LandingModule.controller', [
                     'necs.FeaturedItemsModule.directives'])
.controller('LandingController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', '$window', 'ajaxUtil',
function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $window, ajaxUtil){

  $scope.landingProducts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  $scope.getFeaturedProducts = function() {
    ajaxUtil.get('/api/landingProducts', $scope, 'onGetFeaturedProducts');
  };

  $scope.onGetFeaturedProducts = function(response) {
    if (response) {
      $scope.landingProducts = response.data;
    }
  };

  $scope.getCatalogMailer = function(id){
    if (id == 'link1'){
        $window.open("link");
    }else if(id == 'link2'){
        $location.url('link');
    }else if(id =='link3'){
        $location.url('link');
    }else if(id =='link4'){
        $location.url('link');
    }else if(id =='link5'){
        $location.url('link');
    }
  };

  $scope.getFeaturedProducts();

  ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'title': 'landing page'
  });
}]);
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="necs">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NECS</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/icon.png" sizes="32x32" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js"></script>


    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angularUtils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-67702514-1', {
        'cookieDomain': 'none'
      });
  </script>

  <base href="/" />

  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="15">
    <div class="container">
      <header-directive></header-directive>
      <div ng-view >
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="main-footer">
        <div class="container">
          <footer-directive></footer-directive>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**LANDING.HTML**

```
<div class="landing row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="well">
        <custom-order-directive></custom-order-directive>
        <featured-items-directive></featured-items-directive>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="item in landingProducts" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail main-container">
      <div class="image-container">
        <!--<img ng-click="onProductClick(item.id)" class="top-sellers" ng-src="{{item.img}}" />-->
        <img ng-src="{{item.image}}" />
      </div>
        <div class="caption text-center landinglinks">
        <h3 >{{item.header}}</h3>
        <!--<p ng-bind-html="item.text" ng-click="onProductClick(item.link)"></p>-->
        <p ng-bind-html="item.text" ng-click="getCatalogMailer(item.link)"></p>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FRONT APP.JS**

```
angular.module('necs', ['ngRoute',
                        'necs.LandingModule.controller',
                        'necs.CustomModeModule.controller',
                        'necs.CustomOrderModule.controller',
                        'necs.CustomPdfModule.controller',
                        'necs.CatalogModule.controller',
                        'necs.ProductModule.controller',
                        'necs.HeaderModule.directives',
                        'necs.FooterModule.directives',
                        'necs.MenuModule.directives',
                        'necs.DownloadsModule.controller',
                        'necs.InformationModule.controller',
                        'necs.LoginModule.controller',
                        'necs.AccountModule.controller',
                        'necs.AdministrationModule.controller',
                        ])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'html/landing.html',
      controller: 'LandingController'
    })
    .when('/customMode', {
      templateUrl: 'html/customMode.html',
      controller: 'CustomModeController'
    })
    .when('/customOrder', {
      templateUrl: 'html/customOrder.html',
      controller: 'CustomOrderController'
    })
    .when('/customPdf', {
      templateUrl: 'html/customPdf.html',
      controller: 'CustomPdfController'
    })
    .when('/catalog', {
      templateUrl:'html/catalog.html',
      controller: 'CatalogController'
    })
    .when('/catalog/product', {
      templateUrl: 'html/product.html',
      controller: 'ProductController'
    })
    .when('/downloads', {
      templateUrl: 'html/downloads.html',
      controller: 'DownloadsController'
    })
    .when('/information', {
      templateUrl: 'html/information.html',
      controller: 'InformationController'
    })
    .when('/cart', {
      templateUrl: 'html/cart.html',
      controller: 'CartController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'html/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/account', {
      templateUrl: 'html/account.html',
      controller: 'AccountController'
    })
    .when('/administration', {
      templateUrl: 'html/administration.html',
      controller: 'AdministrationController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

**SERVER APP.JS**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');
var db = require('./db')();
var user = require('./user')();
var fs = require('fs');
var Cookies = require('cookies');

var Product = require('./product');
var Category = require('./category');
var Download = require('./download');
var Codes = require('./codes');
var Specsheet = require('./specsheet');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../front/static')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.get('/qr/:qrcode', function (req, res) {
    var domain = 'domain.com/#/qr/';
    var qrcode = req.params.qrcode;

    res.redirect(domain+qrcode);
});

//login
app.use(flash());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var server = app.listen(80);

var config = {
  "USER": "user",
  "PASS": "password",
  "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
  "PORT": "22222",
  "DATABASE" : "database"
};

var dbPath  = "mongodb://" + config.USER + ":"+ config.PASS + "@"+ config.HOST + ":"+ config.PORT + "/"+ config.DATABASE;
mongoose.connect(dbPath);

db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log('connected successfully');
});


//landing products
app.get('/api/landingProducts',function(req,res) {

  var landingItems = {
      landing1: {
          image: "/assets/images/landing1.jpg",
          text: "text1",
          header: "header1",
          link: "link1"
      },
      landing2: {
          image: "/assets/images/landing2.jpg",
          text: "text2",
          header: "header2",
          link: "link2"
      },
      landing3: {
          image: "/assets/images/landing3.jpg",
          text: "text3",
          header: "header3",
          link: "link3"
      },
      landing4: {
          image: "/assets/images/landing4.jpg",
          text: "text4",
          header: "header4",
          link: "link4"
      },
      landing5: {
          image: "/assets/images/landing5.jpg",
          text: 'text5',
          header: "header5",
          link: "link5"
      },
      landing6: {
          image: "/assets/images/landing6.jpg",
          text: "text6",
          header: "header6",
          link: "link5"
      }
  };

  res.send(landingItems);

});
```

Comment: where are you `bootstraping` you angular app ?

Comment: @UsmanRana Were you able to figure out anything?

Comment: Which version of IE are you trying to use? Also, does changing the order of the dependencies change the result? Is it always that controllers, or just the first on in the list?

Comment: @oatmealsnap I'm using IE 11.  I imagine most people are using 10 or 11.  I also just switched the order of the dependencies and the error occurred on the first one it hit (regardless of which one it was.) Line 2 after ngRoute.

Comment: EDIT: ADDED index.html code

Comment: Can you show what's exactly in `controllers.js` file?

Comment: It's already posted up above.  It contains other controllers, but it starts with landing module in full as you see above.

Comment: Have you tried swapping script tag position for controller.js & app.js? (Like 1st controller.js & then app.js)

Comment: @Shantanu, within Index.html? Yes. This unfortunately didn't change anything.  So far I've not been able to even generate another error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested on IE 11:

This is what I am getting: Expected ':' in controllers.js (1551,3)

It looks like you have declared 3 additional variables, but not properly:

```
$scope.getWidthDropdown = {
    warr
};
```

And there are two others.

You should change that to

```
$scope.getWidhtDropdown = {
    warr: warr
};
```

I am not sure if that will fix the issue though.  Could be a red herring

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: As a note:  You posted your local database credentials in this thread.  I would recommend changing the password at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for looking out, but those are actually fake!

Comment: WOW, that actually fixed it!  I never thought it would be so simple. I've been so focused on the app.js portion that I never thought to look at my variables in my controller.  Enjoy your Bounty!

Comment: Transpiling with Babel would take care of this for you.